# Edit Path URL showing all ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So as a rails newbie, I can't work this one out.  I have a Student model that has many Detentions, Inschools and Suspensions.  I want to be able to create, show and link to the edit in the Student show page. If a Student has only one Detention, not a problem. But if there is more than one, the edit_student_detention_path puts all of the student's detention_id in the url. Probably an easy fix, but I am missing it.

Student Controller:

```
def show
@student = Student.find(params[:id])
@detention = @student.detentions.new
@detentions = @student.detentions.all
@inschool = @student.inschools.new
@inschools = @student.inschools.all
@suspension = @student.suspensions.new
@suspensions = @student.suspensions.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @student }
end
end
```

Student Show View:

```
<% @student.detentions.each do |detention|%>

  <tr>
 <td><%= detention.detention_date %></td>
 <td><%= detention.administrator %></td>
 <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_student_detention_path(@student, @detentions) %></td>
 <td><%= link_to "Letter", student_detention_path(@student, @detentions) %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about what you really want but if you're trying to link to the detention's edit view, just change your link_to from :

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_student_detention_path(@student, @detentions) %>
```

to :

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_detention_path(detention) %>
```

Comment: When I do this, I get an "undefined method `edit_detention_path'"

Comment: Well, I assumed you had previously generated the detentions as resources : with a controller and routes. If you have a controller for the detentions maybe you need to set up some routes in config/routes.rb like so : `resources :detentions`

Comment: Thanks for your patience. My route is setup as `resources :students do resources :detentions end`. I think the controller is getting all of the students detention_ids and placing them in the URL, but I am not sure how to fix.

Comment: Oops, I just edited my answer, I meant `edit_detention_path(detention)` not @detentions sorry. But from what I saw, the problem might lie somewhere else, never used nested resources but I think what you really want is in fact `edit_student_detention_path(@student, detention)` so you were actually closer than me. You can try both of them but I think the last one should do the trick ; )